# Change the variations by button next

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```js
//buttons
$(document).ready(function() {

$('<div class="select_arow_wrap"><span id="select-up" class="select-up"></span><span id="select-down" class="select-down"></span><div/>').appendTo('td.value:first');
 
$('<img id="upArrow" src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1182/PNG/512/1490129325-rounded01_82184.png" style="float : right; width: 30px; height: 20px;" />').appendTo('td.value:first');
$('<img id="downArrow" src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1182/PNG/512/1490129347-rounded02_82188.png" style="float : right; width: 30px; margin-left: -30px; height: 20px;   margin-top: 20px;" />').appendTo('td.value:first');
});
//action
$(document).ready(function() {

    var nextListitem;
        var noOfListItems = $("select#pa_couleur > option").length-1;
        var curListItem = $("select#pa_couleur")[0].selectedIndex;
        $("#upArrow").on("click", function(){
            nextListitem = (curListItem-1 < 0) ? noOfListItems : curListItem-1;
            curListItem = nextListitem;
            $("select#pa_couleur")[0].selectedIndex = nextListitem;
        });
        $("#downArrow").on("click", function(){
           nextListitem = (curListItem+1 > noOfListItems) ? 0 : curListItem+1;
            curListItem = nextListitem;
            $("select#pa_couleur")[0].selectedIndex = nextListitem;
        });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
                        <td class="label">
                          <label for="pa_couleur">Color</label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="value" data-children-count="1">
                            <select id="pa_couleur" class="" name="attribute_pa_couleur" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_couleur" data-show_option_none="yes">
                            <option value="">Option:</option>
                            <option value="blue" class="attached enabled">Blue</option>
                            <option value="grey" class="attached enabled">Grey</option>
                            </select><div class="select_arow_wrap"><span id="select-up" class="select-up"></span>
                            <span id="select-down" class="select-down"></span>
                            <div></div></div><img id="upArrow" src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1182/PNG/512/1490129325-rounded01_82184.png" style="float : right; width: 30px; height: 20px;">
                            <img id="downArrow" src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1182/PNG/512/1490129347-rounded02_82188.png" style="float : right; width: 30px; margin-left: -30px; height: 20px;   margin-top: 20px;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

How is it possible change variations of the product page by clicking to the "next" (and "before") button? To change the dropdown list into the field of one displaying variation which is chosen by clicking to this button ? Something like [this](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-plus-minus-buttons-to-add-to-cart-quantity-input/) but for variations. Maybe you have any ideas

Comment: give code exemple of what you whant...what do you mean saying "variants"??

Comment: Sorry, there are "product variations", not variants

Comment: did you try to use the same js logic but using the list as array and the value display in a textbox?

Comment: The main problem is in a cart: even if the variations are chosen, the cart isn't active

Comment: Using the list as array and value in a textbox But the value will get the same problem: no possibility to add to cart again, the example with a quantity button shows it

Comment: your cart work on other parts? or just this part?

Comment: I'm looking for a AJAX solution but can't figure it out

Comment: Just this part, the quantity (in the example it's like the same idea of what I want for variations) is working, add to cart is available just for a product type 'simple'

Comment: you need to show your code to see if you got any error on it